# Jquery Trasform Scale, but keep orgin NOT working AT ALL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to scale an image on each button click, while maintaining it's orgin. However, I can't seem to get the orgin to stay in place (keep top / left) while scaling right side and bottom of image. Currently if you scale, top and left side of image get cut off.

Please see my JSfiddle attached as comment below.

```js
let scale = 1;

$('#myBtn').click(function(){
        scale+=0.1;
   $('#my-image').css({'transform':'scale(' + scale + ')' });
   $('#my-image').css({'transform-orgin':'top left'});
})
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style = "overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll">
  <div style="max-width: 800; height: 600">
    <img id="my-image" src="https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2017/03/castle_moat-100714623-large.jpg" clss="img-fluid"/>
  </div>
</div>

<button id=myBtn> Zoom In </button>
```

Comment: Please see my JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1bLtk2zj/15/

Comment: Typo. `orgin` needs to be `origin`. Voting to close.

Comment: That's not the reason

Comment: Yes it is: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nr1e0wy3/

Comment: If you are not changing the transform-origin on the click, just add it to css instead of javascript